# Apache POI getFontIndex : incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short

Tags: java, apache-poi

I migrate Apache POI from 3.17 to 5.2.2.

The code below produces an error "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short" in compile step on third line and I don't understand why because getFontIndex return a short and getFontAt take a short too.

Can you help me please ?

```
Workbook wb = sheet.getWorkbook();
CellStyle cellStyle = longestTextCell.getCellStyle();
short fontIndex = cellStyle.getFontIndex();
Font excelFont = wb.getFontAt(fontIndex);
```

PS : fontIndex is not used elsewhere.

Comment: Using `apache poi 5.2.2` [CellStyle.getFontIndex](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.java?view=markup#l56) returns a `int` and [Workbook.getFontAt](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_5_2_2/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.java?view=markup#l309) expects a `int` too.

Comment: Thanks. Intellij needed to rebuild Maven projects in addition to mvn clean install to get the update.